# How to check update values in the plist file

Tags: iphone, xcode, plist

I have added the plist file in the NSBundle and now i update the vaules in the plist file but i can not find a way to check whether the value is updated or not in the plist file in the NSBundle. Is there a way to check this?

What i want is like local database checking, means if we use local database then we can check the updation of the database in the document directory so we can verify the entry is done, like that i want to check in plist file..

I know how to read from plist file but i do not want to write code to check the entries, I hope you understand what i want to say?

Comment: well you can use KeyValue Observer (Just look into apple docs) The NSKeyValueObserving (KVO) informal protocol defines a mechanism that allows objects to be notified of changes to the specified properties of other objects.

You can observe any object properties including simple attributes, to-one relationships, and to-many relationships. Observers of to-many relationships are informed of the type of change made — as well as which objects are involved in the change.

Comment: @Praveen-K don't know how I missed it, may be because I never used it myself.

Comment: So are you able to do that with KVO ?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use **KeyValue Observer** (*Just look into apple docs*)

The **NSKeyValueObserving (KVO)** informal protocol defines a mechanism that allows objects to be notified of changes to the specified properties of other objects.

You can observe any object properties including simple attributes, to-one relationships, and to-many relationships.

Observers of to-many relationships are informed of the type of change made — as well as which objects are involved in the change.

Comment: Can you provide me some little example if possible?